# Get local IPs, then test for port 443 listening in Powershell

Tags: powershell

So here's what I'm trying to do...  I want to run a script that enumerates all the local IPs on a system that are listening on port 443 and export a list of those IPs.

Here's what I have so far:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter IPEnabled=TRUE -ComputerName . | Format-Table -Property IPAddress
```

However that is outputting like such:

```
IPAddress                                                                                                                                                                             
---------                                                                                                                                                                             
{10.206.147.139, 10.206.147.138, 10.206.147.137, 10.206.147.136...}                                                                                                                   
{172.18.4.24}
```

How can I get this list in a complete format (no truncating with "...").  Also, any ways to remove the brackets so I just have a comma separated list?  I think I can handle it from there.  As always, THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured this out...

```
gwmi Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration |
    Where { $_.IPAddress } | # filter the objects where an address actually exists
    Select -Expand IPAddress | # retrieve only the property *value*
    Where { $_ -like '10.*.*' }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a .Net Socket to make a connection to port 443:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter 'IPEnabled=TRUE' | Select -ExpandProperty IPAddress | % {
   $Socket = New-Object Net.Sockets.TcpClient
   $Socket.Connect($_, 443)
   If ($Socket.Connected) {
      $Socket.Close()
      Write-host "$port open on $_"
   }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that returns "open on <ipaddress>" for every IP, even ones that don't have port 443 bound to them....

Comment: Try connecting remotely, instead of locally (you may also need a `Try Catch` in that case).